# 14.04 on AWS server 500 error

Tags: server, apache2, lamp

My Ubuntu LAMP stack works perfectly. I can also use phpMyAdmin without error from docroot.

However after installing Magento2 AND confirming that it installed correctly. I now get a server 500 error ONLY when trying to access the magento app. Access to everything else continues to work fine.

Symptoms? Web browser displays a completely blank page. Browser debugger just reports server 500 error with no other information.

I've cross-posted this to the Magento group as well but not getting useful traction there.

Any pointers to resolving this are deeply appreciated.

From most recent access.log

```
174.20.108.232 - - [04/Mar/2016:21:07:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 184 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/601.5.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1 Safari/601.5.17"
```

From most recent error.log

```
Fri Mar 04 01:15:20.402103 2016] [:error] [pid 1954] [client 174.20.108.232:52539] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException' with message 'Can't create directory /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/.' in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:103\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\\Framework\\Code\\Generator-
generateClass('Magento\\\\Framewo...')\n#1 [internal function]: Magento\\Framework\\Code\\Generator\\Autoloader-
load('Magento\\\\Framewo...')\n#2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\\\\Framewo...')\n#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\\\\Framewo...')\n#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\\Framework\\Code\\Reader\\ClassReader-
getConstructor('Magento\\\\Framewo...')\n#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Definition\\Runtime-
getParameters('Magento\\ in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php on line 103
```

Comment: any webserver logfiles infos? what do access and error log show? could you review them or post the important parts of error.log?

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed the directory/file ownership & permissions conform to the [Magento 2 documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html)?

The error suggests the permissions are wrong since it can't create a new directory.

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception '[...]' with message 'Can't create directory /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/.'

Answer (score 0):

Please check the files and directory permission should be 775, and group ownership should be apache.

Please follow the below commands.

```
 chmod -R 755 /var/www/html 
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/var
chown -R username:www-data /var/www/html
```

If still you are not able to access, please send us apache log.

```
 tail /var/log/apache/error.log
```